# Java Swing align text inside icon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can i align a text to the left of a JButton but the icon is sill centered and isnt pushed away by the text?

The false alignment:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQj0q.png]

I want it more like this but the text is align to the left:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2elnN.png]

I already testes the `setHorizontalAlignment()` and `setHorizontalTextPosition` Methods.
I also want to avoid positioning a Jlabel over the JButton.

My code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Example frame = new Example();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Example() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        JButton settings_bnt = new JButton("settings");
        
        settings_bnt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Example.class.getResource("/grafics/MainGUI/Settings.png")));
        settings_bnt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        settings_bnt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        settings_bnt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        settings_bnt.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        settings_bnt.setBounds(10, 10, 112, 35);
        settings_bnt.requestFocus();
        add(settings_bnt);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are asking. In the first picture I don't see how the Icon is "centered".  The icon looks like it is right aligned to me. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. I'm also not understanding how the `setHorizontalTextPosition doesn't do what you want.

Comment: We can't copy/paste/compile/test that code so see what happens.

Comment: @camickr I added my code snipped. I try to specify my problem a bit more. The second Image is near what i want but as you can see the text is perfectly aligned in the center. This brings up the problem that the text overlaps the icon in the graphic. When im using `setHorizontalTextPosition`  the text isnt anymore obove the graphic and produces results like in the first [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQj0q.png).

Comment: @camickr I've edited the code snipped and it is now working with copy/past.

Comment: Do you want the icon to function as background, text overlapping it? [`setIconTextGap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIconTextGap(int)) indicates that text and icon are placed side-by-side. One probably needs to make a custom JButton.

Comment: @JoopEggen Your right. I want the icon as a background. I tried it with a custom painter but all approaches didn't work. The `setIconTextGap` is a good idea but isn't working for me.

Comment: Make your own extended class of `JButton` with your own `paintComponent`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Ive done it but i still run into the same issue. Do you have a brief Idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't use a null layout. That distorts the size of the button. I still don't see what you want. Is your icon just the "ball" or is the grey color part of your icon? Post your actual image in the forum. I would suggest your icon should just be the "ball". Then you can set the background of the button to be whatever you want and use the `setHorizontalAlignmentTextPosition()` to place the text before the button.

Comment: Or, maybe you can use the [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/). It allows you to combine multiple icons into one. You would also need to use the `TextIcon` which is also found in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One desires a button with the icon image as background.

After a look, the easiest to have a JButton with its normal icon & text & button look was to do:

```
    setIconTextGap(-100);
```

where 100 relates to the left icon's width.

A second alternative would be using HTML text:

```
    URL backgroundURL = getClass().getResource("/background.png");
    String text = "Panic!";
    text = "<html><div style='padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background: url("
        + backgroundURL.toExternalForm() + ")'>"+ text + "</div>";
    setText(text);
```